# Swift: Array not mutating between classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift

I'm working on a swift project where I create a custom keyboard. In my ViewController, I store and mutate an array of UIImages. Then, in my Keyboard module in my keyboardViewcontroller.swift I would like to use the data I have in this array to create buttons. However, when I try to access the array in KeyBoardViewController it seems to give me an empty array and throws an index out of bounds error. What is strange to me is that in ViewController I print out the size of my array and it is definitely not empty. Here is how I'm storing the array:

```
import UIKit
class Main {
    var pics :[UIImage]
    init(pics : [UIImage]) {
        self.pics = [UIImage]()
    }
}
var instance = Main(pics: [UIImage]())
```

In ViewController I mutate it with instance.pics.append...

In my KeyboardViewController:

```
for image in instance.pics {
...
}
```

Why would this show as an empty array in KeyboardViewController?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you passing a parameter that you ignore?

Comment: Exactly. Instead of asigning the passed `pics` argument to `self.pics`, you are assigning a new, empty array (`[UIImage]()`).

Comment: Incidentally, the argument passed to the initializer **also** is an empty array of `UIImage`. What would you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than assigning an empty array of UIImage objects, the following will set the internal array variable to **be a copy** of the myPics array.

```
import UIKit

class Main {
    var pics: [UIImage]
    init(pics: [UIImage]) {
        self.pics = pics
    }
}

var instance = Main(pics: myPics)
```

Comment: Thank you! this looks like what I was looking for. one more question though, what is myPics? Is this an array I should create elsewhere? If I try to create an array in ViewController called myPics and say Main(pics: myPics) it says myPics not found

Comment: If you have an existing array of UIImages that you want to save in the Main class, then that would be myPics. Otherwise, create a Main `init` that simply initialises pics as an empty array.